# Как удалить псевдокласс?

Tags: javascript, html, css

На кнопке есть псевдокласс (белый крестик), как его убрать?

```css
.button {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    background-color: #c0392b;
    margin-right: 70px;
    width: 150px;
    height: 45px;
    line-height: 50px;
    right: 0;
    color: #fff;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 16;
    cursor: pointer;
    overflow: hidden;
    border-radius: 30px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    transition: all 0.25s cubic-bezier(0.31, -0.105, 0.43, 1.4);
}

.button span,
.button .icon {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;

}

.button span {
    width: 72%;
    line-height: inherit;
    font-size: 16px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    left: 0;
    transition: all 0.25s cubic-bezier(0.31, -0.105, 0.43, 1.4);
}

.button span:after {
    content: "";
    background-color: #a53125;
    width: 2px;
    height: 70%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 15%;
    right: -1px;
}

.button .icon {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    width: 25%;
    align-items: center;
    right: 0;
    margin-top: 6px;
    transition: all 0.25s cubic-bezier(0.31, -0.105, 0.43, 1.4);
}

.button .icon .fa {
    font-size: 30px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    transition: all 0.25s cubic-bezier(0.31, -0.105, 0.43, 1.4), height 0.25s ease;
}

.button .icon .fa-remove {
    height: 36px;
}

.button .icon .fa-check {
    display: none;
}

.button.success span,
.button:hover span {
    left: -72%;
    opacity: 0;
}

.button.success .icon,
.button:hover .icon {
    width: 100%;
}

.button.success .icon .fa,
.button:hover .icon .fa {
    font-size: 45px;
}

.button.success {
    background-color: #F6B300;
}

.button.success .icon .fa-remove {
    display: none;
}

.button:hover {
    opacity: 0.9;
}

.button:hover .icon .fa-remove {
    height: 46px;
}

.button:active {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
    <a class="button" href="#">
    <span>Корзина</span>
    <div class="icon">
    <img src="img/cart.png">
        <i class="fa fa-remove"></i>
        <i class="fa fa-check"></i>
    </div>
    <script>(function() {
  var removeSuccess;

  removeSuccess = function() {
    return $('.button').removeClass('success');
  };

  $(document).ready(function() {
    return $('.button').click(function() {
      $(this).addClass('success');
      return setTimeout(removeSuccess, 3000);
    });
  });

}).call(this);</script>
</a>
```

Comment: Никак) Сделать другой класс, который повторяет все стили `.button` кроме псевдоэлемента. Удалить старый класс, добавить новый. Или, добавить всем button второй класс со стилями `.button.no-after span:after { display: none; }`

Comment: Выделяете в css строчки после `:after` и жмете кнопку `delete`. Поздравляю, псевдокласс удален

Comment: `button:after, button *:after { display: none !important; }`. easy